# What is the proper typescript type for creating element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

What would the return type be here?

the paths value is a function that returns an element.

```
export type iconName = "logo";

type icon = {
    viewBox: string;
    paths: () => ??;
};

const IconSet: Record<iconName, icon> = {
    logo: {
        viewBox: "0 0 20 20",
        paths: () => (<div>...</div>),
    },
};

export { IconSet };
```

I just want to use it like this in js

```
export const test = {
  a : () => {return (
    <div>...</div>
    
  )}
}
```

my package.json file

[image]

and tsconfig file here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `JSX.Element` from e function that return a JSX element:

```
type icon = {
    viewBox: string;
    paths: () => JSX.Element;
};

const IconSet: Record<iconName, icon> = {
    logo: {
        viewBox: "0 0 20 20",
        paths: () => (<div>...</div>),
    },
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk5g0IA7AORRFYC8cAEQAbCAHMIwiuSYs2HTnCEBvcnE1wAbsCQB3AEIRqALjgBnGFGCcJFLXDAoYACwvmAFAEoVAPjgAKQBlAA0AOgBRUSR+ThgKAF9ZJSs4AEklYKQYc2QOKAATAB52Ll5+ABpFLgC1DS1xKXN1R0ddA2MzEQAGOD6AJkGe4UqGtqcXdy9fAQDPYsLgbT9wteKAeiWV7zHHRLHkyho6eFUMrJy4ZKA)

Comment: I used that but got an error. errorType 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2322)
logo.ts(5, 9): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

Comment: @minami The code in the playground works. Not sure why you are getting an error. If you can post an example with the failure that would help

Comment: Yeah... As you said,  it works well in Codes and Box.

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-glitter-ouizt?file=/src/icon.tsx

Is it a matter of setting up my project?
I uploaded tsconfig.json and package.json. Can you take a look?

Comment: I solved this. It was because I used .ts, not .tsx. so foolish.